# Adjust gamepad bumper button upper deadzone

Tags: hardware-failure, game-controller

I have a problem with my gamepad on PC. I use DualShock 3 from Sony through SCP Driver emulator as X360 pad.

To fully press the right bumper button to 100%, I have to push it all the way down very firmly and with quite a force and when I press it what you would consider normal button press, it locks only at around 75% of maximum range. I suppose the button is starting to be worn out.

Is there a tool that allows to shift the upper range lower, so when I press it normally in its worn state, it gives 100% output?

Comment: What is the make and model of the gamepad?

Comment: @BenN I use DualShock 3 from Sony through SCP Driver emulator as X360 pad.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Right "Trigger", or Right "Bumper"?  The Trigger is the only one that's analog(for 360/XInput controllers), unless you're using a DualShock controller.

There is some software that can change what is considered the max of the press, but you'd have to edit some x360ce.ini and XInput.dll files to get that to work, and it would only really apply to games that use those files for their gamepad support.  I couldn't tell you how to use those.  Search up "x360ce" if you want to give it a shot yourself.

Additionally, M&KB emulators like Xpadder or Antimicro can be used to customize what's considered the max range, however you'd have to disable or remove the game's in-game controller support so you would just be able to have your controller emulate mouse and keyboard events.  Not super ideal, but the easier of the two options.

Sorry, but that's all the help I can offer.